# Inverse of Zenithal projection

Tags: trigonometry, projective-geometry

Zenithal perspective projections are generated from a point *P* and carried through the sphere to the plane of projection as illustrated in the figure below.

[image]

By a simple geometric relationship, we can show that the radius [image: R_\theta] satisfies the following:

[image: 1]

with [image]. The inverse equation is given by:

[image]

where

[image]

I could reproduce the first equation but not the second one. I think the derivation is purely based on algebraic operation of the first one but I have no idea how. Does anyone have any idea how to derive the second equation?

Comment: What do you mean by arg($\rho,1$) ? What is $\rho$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie, arg(rho, 1) denotes arctan(rho/1). The definition of rho is shown in the third equation in the post.

Comment: OK for the definition of $\rho$ I hadn't seen. A remark : instead of "arg(...)" it would be better to use notation arctan$\color{red}{2}$(...)

Comment: @JeanMarie, Right! Thank you for the heads-up! I corrected the notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I will work in radians allowing to neglect factor $\frac{180}{\pi}$.
2. From your drawing, I see that you can express the tangent of the angle in $P$ in two ways :

$$\underbrace{\frac{R_{\theta}}{(\mu+1)}}_{\rho}=\frac{\cos \theta}{\mu+\sin \theta}.$$

Otherwise said :

$$\rho (\mu+\sin \theta)=\cos \theta$$

which is equivalent to :

$$\cos \theta-\rho \sin \theta=\rho \mu$$

Let us divide both sides by $\sqrt{1+\rho^2}$ :

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}\cos \theta-\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}} \sin \theta=\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}} \mu \tag{1}$$

There is an angle $\alpha$ such that :

$$\begin{cases}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}&=&\sin\alpha\\\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}&=&\cos \alpha\end{cases}\tag{1'}$$

A little pause here : let us observe that the ratio of the previous equations gives

$$\frac{1}{\rho}=\tan \alpha \tag{1''}$$

(which is a way to define $\alpha$)

Using (1'), (1) can be transformed into :

$$\sin\alpha \cos \theta-\cos\alpha \sin \theta=\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}} \mu $$

We recognize here an *addition formula* :

$$\sin(\alpha -\theta)=\frac{\rho}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}} \mu$$

giving

$$\alpha - \theta = \sin^{-1}\frac{\rho \mu}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}$$

$$ \theta = \alpha - \sin^{-1}\frac{\rho \mu}{\sqrt{1+\rho^2}}$$

with $\alpha$ given indeed by relationship (1'').

Comment: Beautiful! Makes totally sense. I appreciate your help!